# How to change the size and shape of a CollisionShape (3D) in runtime?

Tags: godot

I'm trying to make my game more dynamic by making attack hitboxes scaleable. However when adding a new shape to the current CollisionShape it shows the correct radius when printing but the radius ingame is not corresponding to the new value.

The code I currently use is this:

```
var shape = CylinderShape.new()
shape.set_radius(new_radius)
shape.set_height(new_height)

$Spatial/CollisionShape.shape = shape
```

When running this I tried to print the current CollisionShape.shape.radius and it showed the new number however ingame the collisionshape is still the old shape and nothing changed (both visually with the debug option on and when testing the collision size)

So my question is: how do I change the shape or size of the shape in runtime.

Things I've already tried:

```
$Spatial/CollisionShape.shape.radius = new_radius
$Spatial/CollisionShape.shape.height = new_height
```

This gave the same result unfortunately. I've also tried to make the shape null before putting the new shape in the CollisionShape. This changed nothing aswell.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I did some searching, and I found a bunch of talk about CollisionShape's being EDITOR HELPERS, and to use ` CollisionObject.shape_owner_get_shape` to access the real, ingame shape. This is from Godot official docs - https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_collisionshape.html.  When I tried to look for more info on shape "owners", there is very little and unsatisfying  documentation about it .

Comment: The best links I found are here: https://godotengine.org/qa/6756/dynamic-creation-of-collision-node-solved 
 - and here -https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/bngrvn/what_is_a_collision_owner_in_a_collisionobject/

Comment: Are you still changing the collision shape anywhere else? I made a quick test project with you code snippet and I can at least seethe shape changing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to update a collisioon shape; you have to create a new one.  I solved it like this, where I have a CSGBox which owns a StaticBody which owns a CollisionShape, and I want to make the static body's collision shape match the CSGBox:

```
var box : BoxShape = BoxShape.new()
box.extents.x = self.width/2
box.extents.y = self.height/2
box.extents.z = self.depth/2

$StaticBody/CollisionShape.shape = box
```

(This script is attached to the CSGBox).